# Ouya Controller on Windows 8 to Emulate a Microsoft 360 Controller

Tags: windows-8, drivers, bluetooth, gaming, game-controller

I thought I'd create a central repository for those looking to get their OUYA controller working in Windows.

Currently there is an underlying Windows driver issue, causing the left/right triggers to be recognized, respectively, as Z-Axis/Z-Rotation as well as button presses 13/14 .

[image: All Buttons Released][image: Left Trigger][image: Right Trigger]

[The Xbox 360 Controller Emulator](https://code.google.com/p/x360ce/) translates a generic gamepad to an emulated instance of a Xbox 360 controller. It is able to map the Ouya controller but the underlying driver issue causes the emulated Right Trigger to remain HIGH (Axes 3) and consequently this button is unusable by games that work with a 360 controller (eg. Batman Arkham Origins [tested today], all buttons except the Right Trigger and D-Pad works).

[image: x360ce mapping and sticky button issue]

**Has anyone made progress in overcoming this issue, in x360ce or at the windows driver level?**

**If not, would anyone know where to start to modify the windows game controller driver or x360ce settings to ignore the z-axis?**

I was intrigued into investigate and work on this out of interest because there is no purely bluetooth game controller on the market to my knowledge.

Comment: I was able to fix the sticky right trigger by setting it to Axes6 and the left trigger to HAxis3, pictures do not reflect this. Only thing remaining id to get x360ce recognizing the d-pad!

Comment: the x360ce.ini contents for the configuration so far -> http://pastebin.com/x85R9CcW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked through the problem with the helpful guys at ngemu.com, x360ce works well with the Ouya game controller given you use their new 32-bit library.

The solution process is documented here -> [Forum thread](http://forums.ngemu.com/showthread.php?p=2130700&posted=1#post2130700).

I've updated the [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/6euBXdQY) with the correct configuration.

Works!!